# Was it possible for an 11-year old boy to travel from the north of Scotland to Paris in 1777?

Tags: scotland, paris

I'm researching a musical scholar called John Gunn, born 1766 near Golspie, north of Inverness in the far north of Scotland. He describes a musical performance in Paris that he witnessed in 1777 (and I know the exact concert). Was it normal for young people to make a journey like this alone? The usual explanations for Scots travelling abroad don;t really apply to him (he wasn't a Jacobite, he wasn't Roman Catholic, and the clearances hadn't begun at that time). The 1871 fire at the Hotel de Ville in Paris destroyed many records including, I think, things like documents concerning visiting foreigners. Any suggestions as to how he made the trip, or how to find any records of him in Paris? I think I've tried the obvious routes...

**Additional information (added by @fred2 via commenters)**

John Gunn (c. 1765-1824) (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gunn_(Scottish_writer)) and [DNB](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gunn,_John_(DNB00))) was a cellist, writer on music and professor who studied in London and taught at Cambridge. His wife, who he married circa 1801 in Edinburgh, was a pianist and also an author.

DNB claims he was born in Edinburgh. The original poster does not provide a source for his assertion that he was born instead in Golspie, but it is fair to note that the old DNB is very often wrong/out of date.

Comment: Seems very unlikely. How could that possibly work? It's not like there was a ship or a train going directly from one destination to another, so the journey would have presumably been very difficult for someone so young. Even much older people taking [the Grand Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Tour) typically had a chaperone.

Comment: Why couldn't he have been a member of the entourage of someone else's Grand Tour. How do you conclude he was traveling alone?

Comment: Have you reasons to believe he was traveling *alone* ?

Comment: Is your source [this?](https://books.google.com/books?id=8LZR-OfzJMAC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=John+Gunn+paris+1777+concert&source=bl&ots=M2GpDyfOq2&sig=ACfU3U2cIMnr5b2hpEBxYL6a3nHHrxrnhg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiju7nFjqfqAhXcJTQIHTk2Bc0Q6AEwCnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=John%20Gunn%20paris%201777%20concert&f=true) In the footnote on pg 28 he mentions the concert in Paris, but also discusses attending several parties for elderly individuals. This might indicate some family connections, which might help to explain his travel at that time.

Comment: You haven't shared much of the relevant information with us. We don't know his social class or his family's financial means. We don't know the purpose of the trip, or why you're thinking that he traveled alone. Could alone mean that he was traveling with a servant, who was just never mentioned? Please edit the question to fill in some of the background for us, or else we're just speculating.

Comment: "Was it normal for young people to make a journey like this **alone**?" - I'd be amazed if that was normal for 11-year old boys in 1777. Even for boys with *rich* parents it surely wouldn't be normal. I imagine boys without rich parents wouldn't be able to afford it.

Comment: Why do you presume he was traveling alone (without for example manservant and tutor) ?  This other possibility was not so uncommon in this time for affluent families .

Comment: How do you know he was 11? _Scotland Births and Baptisms, 1564-1950_ shows no fewer than **3** lads named John Gunn christened in the 1760s in Golspie, Sutherland, Scotland: one on 1 May 1767 (father James), one on 4 November 1766 (father Donald), and one on 16 May 1761 (father Alexr.). The third of these would have been 16 in 1777.

Comment: BTW, _Scotland Marriages, 1561-1910_ records the marriage of a John Gunn to Ann Young occurring on 20 Jul 1802 at Saint Cuthberts, Edinburgh, Midlothian, Scotland (now Saint Cuthberts, Edinburgh, Edinburghshire, Scotland, United Kingdom), which fits the "about this time [1801]" from the _Dictionary of National Biography_ from which Wikipedia gets its information.

Comment: [_A Cambridge Alumni Database_](http://venn.lib.cam.ac.uk/acad/intro.html) does not list a Jo* Gun(n) during the relevant time period, so while he may have taught and written there, either he didn't attend or he is missing from the ACAD for some other reason.

Comment: I have voted to reopen since, given the information provided in various comments, it seems entirely reasonable to provide an answer on the history of children travelling to the continent from remote parts of Britain. FWIW, this would be a short version of my answer: "The question 'was in normal' is not really relevant. The only question you need ask is 'is there any reason to doubt Gunn's account?'. While it certainly wasn't *usual* for children to travel to France from remote parts of Scotland in this era, it certainly happened, and in centuries before 1777." Would provide more if had space.